# how can I promote my Kindle Direct book?

Tags: publishing, marketing

I've started uploading the books I've written to Kindle Direct Publishing.

How can I promote them, on a shoe-string budget?

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this post](http://kindlepreneur.com/list-sites-promote-free-amazon-books/) useful.

From the link:

```
In this article, you will gain:

An understanding of how these book promotion websites work
A list of the best book promotion websites, free and premium
A couple of options in order to not have to do this yourself
```

Best of luck! Promotion is exciting and challenging.

Comment: Would you consider quoting the relevant text of your link? (For more information, see [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers))

Comment: Edited to quote the most relevant portion. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Great! At least if the  page goes down, someone could google something similar now. Thanks for editing.

Comment: @NeilFein, my pleasure! Thanks for the heads-up, too! I'll try to be more careful about that going forward. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many different strategies you could use from social media to blog hops to promotional sites, but there is no quick and simple answer as to which would work best for you. I would suggest joining a writer's forum where other writers discuss the strategies they have used and provide feedback on what has or hasn't worked. One that I use and have recommended frequently is the [Kindle Boards Writer's Cafe](http://www.kboards.com/index.php/board,60.0.html). You will find dozens of discussions there on different strategies, and you can decide for yourself which ones to try.